# Add elements to the standard transport control

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to add a selector into the standard transport control of windows universal apps, so i can select the quality of a video.

I tried to modify the xaml where the standard controls are defined, but the control wasn't effected and the standard control is still dislplayed.

The MediaElement with the standard transport control:

```
<MediaElement AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">

</MediaElement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add a selector into the standard transport control and select the quality of a video, I think only editing the template is not enough.

> To add to or modify the functionality of the transport controls, you must create a new class that's derived from [MediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols.aspx#anatomy).

To create a new class derived from MediaTransportControls:

> 1. Add a new class file to your project.
> 2. Modify the class code to derive from the [MediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols.aspx) class.
> 3. Copy the default style from [MediaTransportControls styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt414180.aspx) into a [ResourceDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.aspx) in your project. This is the style and template you modify.
> 4. Change the [TargetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style.targettype.aspx) of the style to the new custom control type.
> 5. Set the [DefaultStyleKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.defaultstylekey.aspx) of your custom class.
> 6. Add a [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) to your XAML markup and add the custom transport controls to it.

For more information, please see [Create custom transport controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187271.aspx) and also the official [Media transport controls sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls) in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Open Blend or on VS2015 click View->Other Windows-> Document Outline(ctrl+alt+T)

add MediaTransportControls in xaml

```
 <MediaTransportControls />
```

No go to Document Outline and right click on the MediaTransportControls -> Edit Template -> Edit Copy (I have a styles.xaml i choose to put it there, you can just click ok)

Now the Document Outline changes view to MediaTransportControls Template and you can change it to your likes. ex. I added a play/pause in the middle.

Doing this in Blend gives you better access, such as, to edit states.

After you done customizing you can add it in you MediaElement like this

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" >
      <MediaElement.TransportControls>
             <MediaTransportControls Style="{StaticResource MediaTransportControlsStyle1}"/>
      </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```