# My implementation of MediaTransportControls does not appear at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to add a quality selector to my `MediaTransportControls`. I started by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) on Microsoft's website. But when I run my app, the controls do not appear at all. I also looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697831/add-elements-to-the-standard-transport-control), but it just links back to the original guide.

What follows are the relevant portions of my code:

`generic.xaml`, contains the quality button:

```xml
...
<AppBarToggleButton x:Name='RepeatButton'
    Style='{StaticResource AppBarToggleButtonStyle}'
    MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='1'
    Visibility='Collapsed'>
    <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
        <SymbolIcon x:Name="RepeatSymbol" Symbol="RepeatAll" />
    </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
</AppBarToggleButton>
<AppBarButton x:Name="QualityControl"
    Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"
    MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder="1">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <ListPickerFlyout x:Name="QualityFlyout"/>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
<AppBarButton x:Name='ZoomButton'
    Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
    MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='9'>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE799;" />
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
...
```

`QualityMediaTransportControls.cs`:

```
public sealed class QualityMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls {
    public QualityMediaTransportControls() {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(QualityMediaTransportControls);
    }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml`:

```xml
...
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" AutoPlay="True">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <local:QualityMediaTransportControls x:Name="qMtc"
            IsSkipBackwardButtonVisible="True"
            IsSkipBackwardEnabled="True"
            IsSkipForwardButtonVisible="True"
            IsSkipForwardEnabled="True"
            IsVolumeButtonVisible="False"/>
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
...
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following sample directly to see whether you've missed anything:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls
The sample is simple but it contains everything you need. Your exist code seems do not have any error.